# Passing Weak Convergence Through a Function?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $f_k,f : \mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$. Assume $f_{k}$ converges weakly to $f$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Let $p:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be some function.

What can say about the weak convergence of $p(f_k)$ (what are some general assumptions on $p$ that one would expect to need)? The reason I ask is I have two terms in an equation in which I want to evaluate as $k\to\infty$, these are

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \varphi_1(x)f_k(x)+ \varphi_2(x)p(f_k(x))~dx  $$

where $\varphi_i\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$, infinitely differentiable compact support, i.e are test functions. I don't mind if I can evaluate this limit $k\to\infty$ up to a subsequence.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible unless $p$ is affine.

Indeed, if $p$ is not affine, then there are $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$ such that
$$
p( \lambda \, a + (1-\lambda) \, b) \ne \lambda \, p(a) + (1-\lambda) \, p(b).$$

Let us denote the support of $\varphi_2$ by $C$ and the Lebesgue measure by $\mu$. For simplicity, I will assume that $\varphi_2 = 1$ on $C$,
otherwise the argument still works but is a little bit more technical.

Now, we can construct a sequence $f_k$, such that each $f_k$ only takes the values $a$ and $b$ on $C$ with
$$ \mu(\{ x \in C \;|\; f_k(x) = a \}) = \lambda \, \mu(C)$$
and such that $f_k \rightharpoonup f$,
where $f$ equals $\lambda \, a + (1-\lambda)\,b$ on the support of $\varphi_2$.
(This is possible by some standard construction of oscillating sequences).

Then
$$\int \varphi_2 \, p(f_k) \mathrm d\mu = (\lambda \, p(a) + (1-\lambda) \, p(b)) \, \mu(C),$$
but
$$\int \varphi_2 \, p(f) \mathrm d\mu = p(\lambda \, a + (1-\lambda) \, b) \, \mu(C).$$

Comment: You mean that $p(f_k) \rightharpoonup p(f)$ is mantained only for affine $p$, right? Not that weak convergence in general ($p(f_k) \rightharpoonup g\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$) is only for affine $p$.

Comment: Yes, $p(f_k) \rightharpoonup p(f)$ might fail for non-affine $p$. However, I do not understand the second sentence of your comment.

Comment: I meat that your argument is only valid if we want for $p(f_k) $ to converge weakly to $p(f) $; but if we are simply looking for weak convergence of $p(f_k) $, couldn't it happen that it doesn't converge to $p(f) $ but to another function?

Comment: Yes, if you have a Lipschitz bound for $p$, then $p(f_k)$ will be bounded in $L^p$ and, therefore, has a weakly convergent subsequence. The weak limit point might fail to be $p(f)$ and I suspect that you cannot expect that the entire sequence converges.

Answer (score 1):

It seemed a good idea to me to assume $p$ as [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) for some nice resutlts, however in the comments I was shown that it doesn't really get you anywhere by itself, so I have edited the answer cancelling the wrong fact I had wrote, but still what follow works.

Also with the "famous" theorem (1.1 in [here](http://www.math.wisc.edu/%7Ehung/note-DoanhPham.pdf)):

Theorem 1.1. $(1 < p < +\infty)$ Let $\{f_n\}$ be a bounded sequence in $\textit{L}^p(U)$. Then there exists a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ which converges weakly to some $f\in \textit{L}^p(U)$.

With this result you could also argue that, for weak convergence of at least a subsequence of $\{ p(f_k) \}$, you only need the boundedness of $||p(f_k)||_p$.

Comment: This is not true. In your first estimate, you get the absolute value of $f_k(x) - f(x)$ and, consequently, weak convergence will not help you.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but what is written now holds. With the absolute value you have that that integral goes to $0$, the only thing is that to prove the  weak convergence you at least need fotr the composition to be in $L^p$ which would happen for example  if $p$ is bounded.

Comment: If $p$ is also bounded you can prove that $p(f_n) \rightharpoonup f(p)$, in fact, using the definition we would want to show that
$$\lim_{k\to +\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}g[p(f_k)-p(f)]dm=0 \mbox{, } \forall g\in \textit{L}^q(\mathbb{R}^d) \mbox{ (with } \frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p}=1\mbox{)}$$
it suffices to show that
$$\lim_{k\to +\infty} \biggl|\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}g[p(f_k)-p(f)]dm\biggr|\le 0 \mbox{ for these } g \mbox.$$

Comment: This is provable, in fact
$$\lim_{k\to +\infty} \biggl|\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}g[p(f_k)-p(f)]dm\biggr| \le \lim_{k\to +\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|g||p(f_K)-p(f)|dm\le$$
$$\le K\lim_{k\to +\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|g||f_k-f|dm=K\cdot 0 \mbox,$$
using, again, weak convergence of $f_k$ and the fact that by definition, also $|g|\in \textit{L}^q(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Comment: Weak convergence only yields $\int |g| \, (f_k - f) dm \to 0$, but not $\int |g| \cdot |f_k - f| dm$. The standard example is $f_k(t) = \sin(k \, \pi \, t)$ on $[0,1]$. You have $f_k \rightharpoonup 0$, but $|f_k| \rightharpoonup 2/\pi \ne 0$.

Comment: I am not saying $\int |g| \cdot ||f_k| - |f|| dm\to 0$, but $\int |g| \cdot |f_k - f| dm$ which is equal to $\int_{\{f_k-f\ge 0\}} |g|  (f_k - f) \,dm+\int_{\{f_k-f< 0\}} |g| \, (f- f_k) dm$ where both terms are positive and go $\to 0$ for weak convergence (if $\int |g| \, (f_k - f) dm \to 0$, then $-\int |g| \, (f - f_k) dm \to 0$). Does't this happen?

Comment: In my counterexample, I have $f_k \rightharpoonup 0 = f$ and $|f_k - f| \rightharpoonup 2/\pi \ne 0$. In your argument, you integrate over a domain which depends on $k$. This does not work well with weak convergence.